# Проблема с формулой Байеса

Tags: python, теорема-байеса

Задача на формулу Байеса состоит в определении биатлониста, который делает пять выстрелов, по событиям, которые могли произойти в течение этих пяти выстрелов. У выстрела есть одна характеристика: попал-не попал. У биатлониста две, которые могут быть только меньше единицы и больше нуля: точность выстрела и "хладнокровность", на которую помножается точность в случае успешного выстрела. То есть, если точность у биатлониста - 0.9, а хладнокровие - 0.8, и первый выстрел успешный, то следующий будет совершаться с точностью 0.9х0.8, в случае если и он был успешен, то третий будет совершен с точностью 0.9х0.8х0.8 и так далее до тех пор, пока биатлонист не промахнется.

Существуют три события: первые три выстрела успешны, последний выстрел успешен и хотя бы три выстрела успешны. Для определения, который биатлонист стреляет, мы используем формулу Байеса:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения],
где в нашем случае P(A|B) - вероятность того, что сейчас стрелял биатлонист j и при этом произошло событие B, P(Aj) - априорная вероятность, что стрелял биатлонист j, P(B|A) - вероятность того, что при стрельбе этого биатлониста произошло событие B.

На основании сотни серий выстрелов мы строим график распределения этих вероятностей для каждого биатлониста: в конце мы обязательно должны получить, что один из биатлонистов с вероятностью в 99% оказывается тем, кто стрелял.

Вот код, реализующий это:

```
from random import random

from pylab import *



import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#имитация выстрела 
def hit(acc):
    if random() > acc:
        return False
    else:
        return True

#массив из пяти выстрелов одного биатлониста
def shooting(acc, composure):
    h = True
    hs = []
    def shoot(cur, n):
        if (n==0):
            return {}
        else:
            h = hit(cur)
            hs.append(h)
            if h==1 :
                shoot(cur*composure, n-1)
            else :
                shoot(acc, n-1)
            return hs
    return shoot(acc, 5)

#класс биатлонистов
class Bth:
    def __init__(self, acc, compos, num):
        self.a = acc
        self.c = compos
        self.i = num

    def avg_acc(self):
        hits = 0
        for i in range(10000):
            hits = hits + shooting(self.a, self.c).count(True)
        return hits/50000
    
    def apriori(self, event):
        c = 0
        for i in range(10000):
            c = c + event(shooting(self.a, self.c))
        return c/10000
    
#создание биатлонистов
bth_1 = Bth(0.99, 0.99, 1)
bth_2 = Bth(0.99, 0.85, 2)
bth_3 = Bth(0.85, 0.97, 3) 
bth_4 = Bth(0.70, 0.70, 4)

#события для проверки гипотез 
def Hit_last(hit_list):
    if hit_list[4] == True:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def First3(hit_list):
    if (hit_list[0] == True) and (hit_list[1] == True) and (hit_list[2] == True) and (hit_list[3] == False):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def Hit3(hit_list):
    if hit_list.count(True) == 3:
        return True
    else:
        return False

#начальная таблица вероятностей 
tab = [(Hit_last, [bth_1.apriori(Hit_last), bth_2.apriori(Hit_last), bth_3.apriori(Hit_last), bth_4.apriori(Hit_last)]), (First3, [bth_1.apriori(First3), bth_2.apriori(First3), bth_3.apriori(First3), bth_4.apriori(First3)]), (Hit3, [bth_1.apriori(Hit3), bth_2.apriori(Hit3), bth_2.apriori(Hit3), bth_4.apriori(Hit3)])]
tabb = [[Hit_last, [bth_1.apriori(Hit_last), bth_2.apriori(Hit_last), bth_3.apriori(Hit_last), bth_4.apriori(Hit_last)]], [First3, [bth_1.apriori(First3), bth_2.apriori(First3), bth_3.apriori(First3), bth_4.apriori(First3)]], [Hit3, [bth_1.apriori(Hit3), bth_2.apriori(Hit3), bth_2.apriori(Hit3), bth_4.apriori(Hit3)]]]

#формула Байеса 
def bayes(hs, pah):
    pa = 0
    mul = []
    for i in range(4):
        mul.append(hs[i]*pah[i])
        pa = pa + mul[i]

    for i in range(4):
        mul[i] = mul[i]/pa
    
    return mul

first,snd = zip(*tab)
tb = bayes([0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25], snd[0])

#проверка того, что указанное событие произошло
def check_event(shooting, hs, event):
    if event[0](shooting) == True:
        return bayes(hs, event[1])
    else:
        return hs

#составление одного элемента изменения вероятностей
def step (hs, shooting):
    hss = hs
    a = hs
    for i in tab:
        a = check_event(shooting, hss, i)
        hss = a
    return hss


#составление массива изменения вероятностей
def chain(hs, shots):
    hss =[]
    a = hs
    hss.append(hs)
    for i in shots:
        hss.append(step(a, i))
        a = step(a, i)
    return hss

def chain_two(real, hs, it):
    new_hs = step(hs, shooting(real.a, real.c))
    max_hs = max(new_hs)
    max_name = new_hs.index(max_hs)
    if max_hs <= 0.99:
        return chain_two(real, new_hs, (it+1))
    else:
        return [it, max_name+1]

def experiment(real, n):
    shootings = []
    hs_chain = []
    hs_0 = [0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25]
    for i in range(n):
        shootings.append(shooting(real.a, real.c))
    hs_chain = chain(hs_0, shootings)
    return hs_chain

def correctness(real):
    c = 0
    for i in range(1000):
        a = chain_two(real, [0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25], 1)
        if a[1] == real.i:
            c = c+1
    return c

#разделение массива на гипотезы для построение графика
с = 50
x = []
x = np.arange(1, с+1)
y = [[], [], [], []]
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(с):
        y[i].append(experiment(bth_1, с)[j][i])
for i in range(4):
    print(y[i])

data = {'Bth1':y[0],
        'Bth2':y[1],
        'Bth3':y[2],
        'Bth4':y[3]
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

plt.plot(x, df)
plt.legend(data, loc=2)
```

И вот графики, которые получаются:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Графики строятся на основе массива, получаемого функцией `experiment`. Выглядит он примерно так:

```
[0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25]
[0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25]
[0.3792694997875744, 0.23482077817348287, 0.2628066972314815, 0.12310302480746128]
[0.4446615388736015, 0.2166269438232587, 0.25648521232170535, 0.0822263049814344]
[0.5079144001921128, 0.19470079913429567, 0.24387514742012506, 0.05350965325346656]
[0.5677505589689683, 0.17124940869375804, 0.2269231712463593, 0.03407686109091433]
[0.623347375978675, 0.14794352006060396, 0.20739374985828454, 0.021315354102436446]
[0.6742239661579332, 0.12591118178828142, 0.1867299449722185, 0.013134907081566907]
[0.6742239661579332, 0.12591118178828142, 0.1867299449722185, 0.013134907081566907]
[0.7611173778337486, 0.08800358332559752, 0.1460662671267819, 0.004812771713872008]
[0.1107881599223399, 0.5903354333309676, 0.29422361129970165, 0.004652795446990872]
[0.5035367172128449, 0.24470726236915472, 0.24909263469729012, 0.0026633857207102925]
[0.8560221864809725, 0.04821882743894818, 0.09475804191269611, 0.0010009441673831836]
[0.8794033767414301, 0.0389775067315875, 0.08103328415823081, 0.0005858323687516956]
[0.04108298655839715, 0.7239837319200692, 0.23411103448043952, 0.0008222470410941119]
[0.1947222018535356, 0.5054798872976519, 0.29828568279523027, 0.0015122280535821782]
[0.930348034415582, 0.02008881303385196, 0.04944854535446966, 0.00011460719609634052]
[0.781183971098587, 0.09010208688133364, 0.12857264966550794, 0.000141292354571511]
[0.8144216973311392, 0.07391373758968131, 0.11158064322376827, 8.3921855411052e-05]
[0.9521646722680064, 0.012729445923263255, 0.0350678103679625, 3.807144076776924e-05]
[0.868689342743016, 0.048812261135401894, 0.08246934177983271, 2.9054341749436753e-05]
[0.5764684427759854, 0.21989652302485424, 0.2035853451623595, 4.968903680093939e-05]
[0.9086083728201799, 0.03161038395522232, 0.05977137942847933, 9.863796118426984e-06]
[0.9240944870653002, 0.02529669111772521, 0.05060310644982243, 5.715367152169413e-06]
[0.9848065302483646, 0.0031247420251024082, 0.012067381244432839, 1.3464821001411824e-06]
[0.987461632998192, 0.0024653454435134337, 0.010072252374195352, 7.691840991951641e-07]
[0.12112756777823377, 0.6422647918763403, 0.2366034782978831, 4.162047542898134e-06]
[0.4109690364534598, 0.16504862601277498, 0.4239170179231306, 6.531961063470784e-05]
[0.9570081239745941, 0.012762797220973376, 0.03022798428219982, 1.0945222327105302e-06]
[0.5940362341520545, 0.22604170206644908, 0.17992059917926584, 1.464602230547144e-06]
[0.9914595669650347, 0.0015325729729565708, 0.007007609389977371, 2.506720314108889e-07]
[0.6445222738311269, 0.1929780284701673, 0.1624987923725073, 9.053261985082501e-07]
[0.8859938515121171, 0.015809809514713398, 0.0981930593139972, 3.2796591722350167e-06]
[0.996719547839598, 0.00046471922649285306, 0.0028157178085441276, 1.512536494006168e-08]
[0.9865103136700916, 0.0031224657747762606, 0.010367181974174052, 3.8580958179834736e-08]
[0.9865103136700916, 0.0031224657747762593, 0.010367181974174048, 3.858095817983473e-08]
[0.9981468146751528, 0.00022672269539158972, 0.0016264598284852925, 2.8009704005765083e-09]
[0.03888333825638996, 0.5648722611694291, 0.39624373168043975, 6.688937412308291e-07]
[0.9611759010289654, 0.012786919357196098, 0.02603714817014519, 3.1443693290310694e-08]
[0.9957703256721729, 0.0007480335019248087, 0.003481639494243471, 1.3316588371986725e-09]
[0.9367530976075567, 0.025517498194852942, 0.03772939945739406, 4.740196250945942e-09]
[0.9994043016018338, 5.3877520076364704e-05, 0.0005418207821898603, 9.589980515434392e-11]
[0.9918666507905072, 0.0019389685162264877, 0.006194380333129752, 3.601365400491089e-10]
[0.9647827176850703, 0.012803401839566936, 0.02241387957258272, 9.027799557288233e-10]
[0.9918666507905072, 0.0019389685162264896, 0.006194380333129757, 3.6013654004910915e-10]
[0.994492701579675, 0.001203670656487749, 0.004303627646634923, 1.1720234606026775e-10]
[0.9840175830136447, 0.005005828052625032, 0.010976588836724626, 9.700561249963597e-11]
[0.9762625593709461, 0.008021417090482687, 0.01571602324206093, 2.9651033266046195e-10]
[0.9805213257796084, 0.006339219806146812, 0.013139454244580451, 1.6966436831812242e-10]
[0.9962660065934077, 0.0007465690627880572, 0.0029874243056949796, 3.8109286899824395e-11]
```

Как вы можете заметить, коварство происходит в таких строчках как:

```
[0.8560221864809725, 0.04821882743894818, 0.09475804191269611, 0.0010009441673831836]
[0.8794033767414301, 0.0389775067315875, 0.08103328415823081, 0.0005858323687516956]
[0.04108298655839715, 0.7239837319200692, 0.23411103448043952, 0.0008222470410941119]
[0.1947222018535356, 0.5054798872976519, 0.29828568279523027, 0.0015122280535821782]
[0.930348034415582, 0.02008881303385196, 0.04944854535446966, 0.00011460719609634052]
```

Когда одно значение неминуемо быстро убывает, а другое с такой же быстротой возрастает.

В чем может быть проблема этих резких спадов и резких подъемов, которые нарушают формулу Байеса? (сумма всех вероятностей не может быть больше единицы)

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: `y[i].append(experiment(bth_1, с)[j][i])` здесь нормально, что именно `bth_1` жёстко прошит? А вообще сложно понять, что происходит, код большой. Сделайте какие-то проверки поэтапно. Тесты какие-то напишите для своего кода. Со строны ничего непонятно толком, что происходит.

Comment: Нет, `bth_1` написан как пример.

Поэтапные проверки проводились, код начинает себя непонятно вести на последней стадии эксперимента. Сейчас дополню вопрос примером.

Answer (score 3):

Обнаружил, что я идиот, и в моей программе было целых две ошибки.

Первая, связанная с третьим графиком, была опечаткой. Вместо

```
tab = [(Hit_last, [bth_1.apriori(Hit_last), bth_2.apriori(Hit_last), bth_3.apriori(Hit_last), bth_4.apriori(Hit_last)]), (First3, [bth_1.apriori(First3), bth_2.apriori(First3), bth_3.apriori(First3), bth_4.apriori(First3)]), (Hit3, [bth_1.apriori(Hit3), bth_2.apriori(Hit3), bth_2.apriori(Hit3), bth_4.apriori(Hit3)])]
```

нужно было написать

```
tab = [(Hit_last, [bth_1.apriori(Hit_last), bth_2.apriori(Hit_last), bth_3.apriori(Hit_last), bth_4.apriori(Hit_last)]), (First3, [bth_1.apriori(First3), bth_2.apriori(First3), bth_3.apriori(First3), bth_4.apriori(First3)]), (Hit3, [bth_1.apriori(Hit3), bth_2.apriori(Hit3), bth_3.apriori(Hit3), bth_4.apriori(Hit3)])]
```

Вторая же была в самом алгоритме построения массивов данных для графиков. Данный цикл

```
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(с):
        y[i].append(experiment(bth_1, с)[j][i])
```

добавлял к списку `y[i]` каждый раз значения из `с` рандомных наборов. Правильный вариант:

```
y = [[], [], [], []]
o = []
o = experiment(bth_3, c)

for i in range(4):
    for j in range(c):
        y[i].append(o[j][i])
```

Результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]